# What is the most idomatic way to write iterators that map an uncertain number of input items to other objects in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a Lexer. Since lexers emit tokens, I suppose that we can perceive a Lexer as a special iterator that maps certain chunks of `char`s to `Token`s. I therefore expect `Lexer` to store an `Iterator<Item=char>` and manipulate that iterator instead of a `&str` to enable maximum flexibility.

```rust
struct Lexer<T: Iterator<Item=char>> {
    source: T
}
```

Yet I find it hard to manipulate the iterator, since almost all iterator adaptors take ownership, and with generics I cannot change the type of `T` at runtime, unless I switch to `Box`.

```rust
self.source.take_while(|x| x.is_whitespace())
```

A possible workaround is to require that the iterator implement `Clone`, use a clone every time I want to transform it, remember how many characters I have seen, and call `next` that many times. I believe that it is too clumsy.

I wonder if there is an idomatic way to write **iterators that map an uncertain number of input items (in this case, `char`s) into another object (in this case, `Token`s)**?

The most elegant way I can come up with so far is to use `while let` etc. which are not so fluent-style-like. I inspected the implementation of `GroupBy` in `itertools` and found that they use the `while let` approach too.

Comment: You can use [`.by_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref) to avoid taking ownership for iterator chains. e.g. `self.source.by_ref().take_while(|x| x.is_whitespace())` [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b02a464cd53519d3b8d2a30ac1144194)

Comment: @kmdreko Thank you! I didn't know that iterators can take ownership of mutable references too. Now I know to use `(&mut iter)`.

Comment: Glad I could help, does that solve all your problems? I can't tell if that's all you needed, or if you still have issues with something

Comment: @kmdreko So far I've not found any bugs using it. Thank you again! I've been balancing the references when using iterators for a little while, never thought about adding one on my own :)